# Menu hover with fade effect

Tags: jquery, hover, fade, jquery-hover

I have this menu structure:

http://jsfiddle.net/Rochefort/szL2C/

everything is ok. But i want, hover effect fade via jQuery. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need only a few lines code for this and the [jquery color animations plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color):

```
$('.links yan-menu li a ').hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: "#002C6A" }, 'fast');
},
function() {
    $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: "#ffffff" }, 'fast');
});
```

Of course you will have to remove the css code an add the code properly to the page

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with css3 with transitions, like this:

```
.menu-item
{
    // In the transition you define the property that 
    // you want a transition attached to and the duration
    transition: background .5s;
    -moz-transition: background .5s; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition: background .5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: background .5s; /* Opera */
}

.menu-item:hover
{
    background: #CCC; // Or whatever color you choose
}
```

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp

**EDIT**

The jQuery solution to your problem would be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#right_menu li').hover(function() {
        $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: "#002C6A" }, 'fast');
    },
    function() {
        $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: "#ffffff" }, 'fast');
    });
});
```

You do however need to include the jQuery color lib found [HERE](http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/). And also you need to remove the :hover background-color that you set in the css.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Doing this via jQuery is unnecessary and less efficient

Comment: But required if the targeted browser doesn't support css3.

Comment: If people use older browsers they choose not to support the new technologies the web offers like css3. I don't see why the simple background hover isn't enough then. But regardless of that I'll look into a jQuery solution.

Answer (score 0):

As Yan Kun said, you have to include jquery color animations library: http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/jquery.animate-colors-min.js

I improve the code inserting .`stop()` sentence in order to avoid loops when mouse is over several times.

```
$('.links yan-menu li a ').hover(function() {
    $(this).stop();
    $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: "#002C6A" }, 'fast');
},
function() {
    $(this).stop();
    $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: "#ffffff" }, 'fast');
});
```